# How to intercept remote notification from the share extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications

In iOS app to intercept/read/get remote notification we must to implement **UIApplicationDelegate** method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {}
```

But it is not possible to intercept/read/get remote notification in the same way from share extension.

*How to intercept remote notification from the share extensions as it is done in the iOS app?*

Comment: can you make it a little bit clear what you want?

Comment: @zombie More details were added.

Comment: You cant. A share extension is only launched when someone selects it in the share dialog. Your host app can receive a notification and store some information to be shared with your share extension when it is next launched.

Comment: @Paulw11 I found solution how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution how to do it in this way:

**a**. Share extension and Notification Services extension should be set to the same app group. References how to do it can be found here: [Apple: Configuring App Groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW61) & [second](http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions).

**b**. Add "**mutable-content = true**" to a Apple Push Notification.

**c**. Implement Notification Services Extension.

**d**. In the **didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)** func save notifications userInfo to UserDefaults using **notificationKey**.

**e**. In the share extension add KVO for ** notificationKey** for UserDefaults.

```
private var notificationServices = 1
let group = UserDefaults(suiteName: SGConst.groupIdentifier)
group.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "notificationKey", options: .new, context: &notificationServices)
```

**f**. When value for ** notificationKey** was updated get userInfo and update view depending on the notification.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    guard context == &notificationServices else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        return
    }
    // Update depending on notification.
}
```

Comment: I have been searching for such thing for long time. this way, you will be able to save the content of notification even if user did not click on it right? if so, may you share a bit more details about the steps 1-5-6 ? it is not clear how we can do those. Thank you

Comment: @MBH You are right. It will be saved even without user interaction. I will be able to add more information only in several days.

Comment: Super awsome ! can you please share some details or sample project on github ?

Comment: @MBH I posted more details and URLs how to achieve it. Is it enough information?

Comment: still not able to implement it, nothing is happening when i receive the notification

Comment: @MBH Do you have sample code online where you are trying to implement it. I could quickly do review.